# DeprecationWarning: grpc.load, Use the @grpc/proto-loader instead

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using node with google firebase and always I

> (node:13556) DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

my node version is a latest

```
$ node -v
v10.14.1
```

Comment: What version of Firebase's libraries are you using? This issue suggests it's fixed in a recent version: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/issues/120

Comment: thanks for your replay , i'm using "firebase": "^5.5.9",

Comment: I have updated it to 5.6.0and still got same error    DeprecationWarning: grpc.load: Use the @grpc/proto-loader module with grpc.loadPackageDefinition instead

Comment: Have replied with a potential fix, but is there any other logging available + could you show all your packages imported?

Comment: @JakeSteam this is all packages 
    "body-parser": "*",
    "cors": "*",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "twilio": "^3.23.2"

Answer (score 7):

`npm install --save grpc`

`npm install --save @grpc/proto-loader`

```js
// replace - const notesProto = grpc.load('notes.proto');
// to

const grpc = require('grpc')
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader')
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync('notes.proto');
const notesProto = grpc.loadPackageDefinition(packageDefinition);
```

Comment: thanks @TechnoL0g, can you explain more about the code, I mean why to use proto-loader in contrast to previous methods?

Answer (score 4):

According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1112), it looks like rolling back to V5.3.0 is a temporary solution, or you could try updating to Node.js 11.2.0.

Comment: i tried to update to node 11.2.0 but i found a bunch of errors due to 11 not stable yet , so it's sounds to wait is a best answer

Comment: Still seeing this same error even on Node.js `v11.10.0`